# Why Instance Variables Get Empty In JavaFX

Tags: javafx

I am using scene builder in development of an interface and when I load the FXML file in my controller.java file I get HBoxes that are defined in my layout.fxml file and it's working fine. But when I add onMouseClicked property on the contents defined in these HBoxes and implements the methods in controller.java file then it throws null pointer exception. It sets all HBoxes variables to null.Here is the code for controller.java file

```
package application;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;


public class Main extends Application {

    private  HBox subTabPaneAppendData;
    private  HBox subTabPaneRecord;
    private  HBox subTabPaneSetting;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        startActivity(primaryStage);
    }

    public void startActivity(Stage primaryStage){

        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/Layout.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,1400,800);

            //getting all the HBoxes from layout.fxml file

            subTabPaneAppendData = (HBox) root.lookup("#subTabPaneAppendData");
            subTabPaneRecord = (HBox) root.lookup("#subTabPaneRecord");
            subTabPaneSetting = (HBox) root.lookup("#subTabPaneSetting");

            subTabPaneAppendData.setVisible(true);
            subTabPaneRecord.setVisible(false);
            subTabPaneSetting.setVisible(false);

            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void appendDataOnClicked() throws IOException{

        //here all the variables are null

        subTabPaneAppendData.setVisible(true);
        subTabPaneRecord.setVisible(false);
        subTabPaneSetting.setVisible(false);
    }

    public void recordOnClicked() throws IOException{

        //here all the variables are null

        subTabPaneAppendData.setVisible(true);
        subTabPaneRecord.setVisible(false);
        subTabPaneSetting.setVisible(false);
    }

    public void searchOnClicked(){      

        //here all the variables are null

        subTabPaneAppendData.setVisible(false);
        subTabPaneRecord.setVisible(false);
        subTabPaneSetting.setVisible(false);
    }

    public void settingOnClicked(){

        //here all the variables are null

        subTabPaneAppendData.setVisible(false);
        subTabPaneRecord.setVisible(false);
        subTabPaneSetting.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void helpOnClicked(){

        //here all the variables are null

        subTabPaneAppendData.setVisible(false);
        subTabPaneRecord.setVisible(false);
        subTabPaneSetting.setVisible(false);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using the `Main` class as controller? Could you show the relevant parts of the fxml? I guess you're adding the `onMouseClicked` handler there.

Comment: Yes I am using Main class as controller and I defined onMouseClicked in .fxml file.

Comment: Don't use the `Application` class as the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the `Main` instance `start` is called for as controller.

By using `fx:controller="application.Main"` you tell the `FXMLLoader` to create a new instance of `Main` as controller. IMHO this is bad for the following reason:
The `Application` class contains a stuff that your controller just doesn't need making the class larger than needed for no good reason.

Furthermore here the `Node`s you look up are written to the fields of the `Main` instance that is run by the javafx platform, not to the fields of the one which is used as controller. Since the method of the new instance is used as event handler, you're calling the method for an instance where the fields are `null` and this causes the NPE.

It would be far better to use a class different to `Main` as controller. Furthermore you can make `FXMLLoader` set the fields automatically by using the `fx:id` attribute with the target field name as value and making sure the field is accessible to the `FXMLLoader` (either it's `public` or annotated with `@FXML`):

#### Controller class

```
package application;

...

public class LayoutController {
    @FXML
    private  HBox subTabPaneAppendData;
    @FXML
    private  HBox subTabPaneRecord;
    @FXML
    private  HBox subTabPaneSetting;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        subTabPaneAppendData.setVisible(true);
        subTabPaneRecord.setVisible(false);
        subTabPaneSetting.setVisible(false);
    }

    public void appendDataOnClicked() throws IOException {
        subTabPaneAppendData.setVisible(true);
        subTabPaneRecord.setVisible(false);
        subTabPaneSetting.setVisible(false);
    }

    public void recordOnClicked() throws IOException {

        subTabPaneAppendData.setVisible(true);
        subTabPaneRecord.setVisible(false);
        subTabPaneSetting.setVisible(false);
    }

    public void searchOnClicked() {
        subTabPaneAppendData.setVisible(false);
        subTabPaneRecord.setVisible(false);
        subTabPaneSetting.setVisible(false);
    }

    public void settingOnClicked() {
        subTabPaneAppendData.setVisible(false);
        subTabPaneRecord.setVisible(false);
        subTabPaneSetting.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void helpOnClicked() {
        subTabPaneAppendData.setVisible(false);
        subTabPaneRecord.setVisible(false);
        subTabPaneSetting.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

#### fxml file

```xml
 ...
 <... xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.LayoutController">
 ...
     <HBox fx:id="subTabPaneAppendData" ...
     ...
     <HBox fx:id="subTabPaneRecord" ...
     ...
     <HBox fx:id="subTabPaneSetting" ...
  ...
```